# Android throwing error Objects are not valid as a React child (found: object with keys{}) when debuger is off but runs when it is on

Tags: android, react-native

When I am running my app in iOS it is running smoothly debugger on/off both cases but in Android it is only running in DEBUG mode and throwing the error

> Objects are not valid as a React child (found: object with keys{}) when debugger is off.

[image]

Well, I believe if there was really problem with rendering an object It would show the same error in iOS but it runs fine in iOS?

package.json

```
{
    "name": "Akash35",
    "version": "0.0.1",
    "private": true,
    "scripts": {
        "start": "node node_modules/react-native/local-cli/cli.js start",
        "test": "jest"
    },
    "dependencies": {
        "@babel/runtime": "^7.3.4",
        "firebase": "^5.8.4",
        "react": "16.6.3",
        "react-native": "^0.58.5",
        "react-native-vector-icons": "^6.2.0",
        "react-navigation": "^2.18.3",
        "react-navigation-material-bottom-tabs": "^0.1.2",
        "react-redux": "^6.0.1",
        "redux": "^4.0.1",
        "redux-thunk": "^2.3.0"
    },
    "devDependencies": {
        "babel-core": "7.0.0-bridge.0",
        "babel-jest": "24.0.0",
        "jest": "24.0.0",
        "metro-react-native-babel-preset": "0.51.1",
        "react-test-renderer": "16.6.3"
    },
    "jest": {
        "preset": "react-native"
    }
}
```

Comment: I am encountering the same problem, have you got a solution?

Comment: Yes Andus, for me it was due to Firebase version try "firebase": "^5.0.3" instead of latest on. let me know if it works Ciao!

Comment: Thanks for replying, in my case the error is caused by 'react-native-qrcode-scanner' for unknown reason. My fix is to put `import QRCodeScanner from 'react-native-qrcode-scanner';` in App.js right before `import React, { Component } from 'react';`(must be put in this particular position), but I do not know why this fix the problem.